# MySQL Match Against with Multiple Values to AGAINST

Tags: mysql, database, match-against

I think this is a very simple query but I just can't find it in any of my programming books or on the net.

I have this query:
SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (column1,column2) AGAINST ('value1');

But I need AGAINST to have multiple values e.g. (value1,value2,value3)

can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [BOOLEAN MODE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-boolean.html) modifier might be what you are looking for.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE MATCH (column1,column2) 
     AGAINST ('+value1 +value2 +value3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: Quick question. According to the link you provided (+value1 +value2) means "Find rows that contain both words." but in my test:
Select * FROM test WHERE MATCH ('title,description') AGAINST ('+val1 +val2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) the result values showed rows without val2. Any ideas?

Comment: nvm the val2 I used was the word "only". I think mysql understands "only" as a stop word. Thanks for boolean mode its what I needed!